# Libgdx TextField won't resize

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, textfield

I have a textfield that simply won't scale, expand ,fill,setWidth nothing works. I have already placed it in a table cell but that didnt help...

This what I have:

[image]

I want the text to scale and fit all the red region...

```
    field = new TextField("", skin4);
    // field.setCursorPosition(0);
    field.setMaxLength(6);
    field.setMessageText("0.00");
    field.setWidth(2f);
    field.setHeight(1f);
    field.setScale(2, 2);
    //group.addActor(field);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setPosition(100, 180);
    table.setSize(150, 90);
    table.add(field).height(80).fill().expand();
    table.setDebug(true);
    table.row();

    group.addActor(table);
    stage.addActor(group);
```

Skin

```
    skin4 = new Skin();
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("future.fnt"), true);
    buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("cursor/cursor.pack"));
    skin4.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    textFieldStyle = new TextField.TextFieldStyle();
    textFieldStyle.font = font;
    textFieldStyle.cursor = skin4.getDrawable("cursor_text");
    textFieldStyle.cursor.setMinWidth(10f);
    skin4.add("default", textFieldStyle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was change my font to a FreeTypeFont generator that can easily scale the font given distorting quality..Like below..

```
        skin4 = new Skin();
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("future.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        //change font size here
        parameter.size = 40;
        parameter.flip = true;
        BitmapFont font25 = generator.generateFont(parameter);

        labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle();
        labelStyle.font = font25;
        skin4.add("default", labelStyle);
```